# missed oil changes

Tags: engine, oil-change

due to covid and other circumstances, I failed to have my oil changed last year on my newish car.  totally my fault and I understand I have caused myself a ton of money here, but just want a second or their opinion.  my oil was obviously really bad - took it for a change and the guy said I'm doomed.  having white smoke upon startup and then okay rest of day.  took it to dealer and said I can try flushing engine but will prob need to have engine replaced.  had engine flushed and guy said engine looks fine, really nothing bad came out of the flush.  car was a little better for a few days and now back to lots of white smoke.  one mechanic said it's not the engine, it's anti-freeze dripping on engine or whatever, but two others said that's not at all the problem.  is replacing my engine the only option now??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! No, engine replacement is the LAST STOP for your journey. It really depends on what the white smoke is and where its coming from exactly. Is it smoking under the hood or is it coming directly out of the tailpipe? I'm tending to agree with the person who did the flush. Old oil isn't going to kill an engine. It will cause a bit more wear, but really, as long as there was oil in the engine,  you shouldn't be seeing issues. The white smoke is most likely from something else besides the old oil.

Comment: Agree with @Paulster2. If you can tell us the year, make, model and engine size it would help. And how many miles did you go without an oil change and did your oil ever get low? Do not authorize an engine replacement until adequate testing is done. It doesn't sound like it has been done at all yet.

Comment: Your engine is "doomed" because of some white smoke on start-up?
Do you often drive for short distances? Might just be condensation buildup.
If you want to be sure, have them do the checks for antifreeze in the oil and vice versa, e.g. Gly-Tek.

Answer (score -1):

Brake fluid leaking past the piston of the brake master cylinder fills the brake booster which is then sucked into the inlet manifold and then through the engine. This causes clouds of white smoke. Have you been losing brake fluid?